# LaTeX support with Movable Type 5?

Tags: latex, movabletype

Is there latex math support with movable type 5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saying the unobvious; but Movable Type 5 cannot be embedded into LaTeX.

Saying the obvious, the other way around:

It is possible using Google's LaTeX image output: See my article on this website http://sites.google.com/site/gencoreoperative/index/articles-and-hacks/google-s-latex

I'll copy some stuff over here, if the link may ever be dead:

```
http://www.google.com/chart?cht=tx&chf=bg,s,FFFFFF00&chco=000000&chl=e^z=\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\frac{z^n}{n!}
```

Where `chl` is your latex, `cht` is "TeX" and `chf` and `chco` are font, style and color attributes.

Update: not sure if it works on sites external from Google too...

Answer (score 1):

http://bitbucket.org/alex_mikhalev/latex/ hasn't been updated in a year. not sure about MT5 support, as I didn't see a mention of version compatibility.